# How do i fix the python parser?

Tags: python

I need a data parser from my website.
I wrote the code in python, but it doesn't work and just gives out the page
https://example.com/api/v1/operators/dialogs/i
But it should output pages with
https://example.com/api/v1/operators/dialogs/1
to
https://example.com/api/v1/operators/dialogs/999...

```
import httpx
import time
from loguru import logger

def parser():
for i in range(1500000):
    logger.info(f"page number {i}")
    session = httpx.Client()

    response = session.get('https://example.com/api/v1/operators/dialogs/i')
    with open ('result.txt', 'a', encoding='utf8') as f:
        f.write(f"{response.text}\n")
    logger.debug(f"Reply from the server {response.text}")
    logger.success("write in txt")
parser()
```

Answer (score 2):

In your line

```
response = session.get('https://example.com/api/v1/operators/dialogs/i')
```

`i` is a normal character. Use f-strings (like in your `logger.info` statement two lines above) to make the string include the value of i.